# Umbraco whitelist backend url for specific IP range

Tags: iis, umbraco, whitelist

I do not want people visiting my site to have access to umbraco backend. so I want to whitelist IP range through IIS who can visit backend url.

I know I can use whitelist and blacklist for IP ranges but it works for the whole site and not for a specific page.

Other approach is to write in global.asax check address from request like `Request.UserHostAddress` and compare it with my list and set the response.

But I want this to be handled through IIS settings.

Is this achievable or it has to be handled by code as below.

```
if(Request.UserHostAddress.Contains("aaa.bbb.cc") // part of IP address here
{
    Response.Redirect("myurl");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IIS Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module to control this. There is a [blog post here](http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2014/03/using-url-rewriting-to-restrict-access) which discusses this and the rule has been reposted below for posterity.

```
<rule name="Restrict Access to Umbraco" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="^/umbraco/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{LOCAL_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.123" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/update-notice/" />
</rule>
```